# Is a biennial flight review valid for any airplane category?

Tags: faa-regulations, usa, currency

If I do a biennial flight review (BFR) in a glider, does it also satisfy my BFR requirement for powered flight (ASEL)?

Comment: Yup, sure does.

Comment: @acpilot Any source for that? [FAR 61.56](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.56) Says that *"A review of those maneuvers and procedures that, at the discretion of the person giving the review, are necessary for the pilot to demonstrate the safe exercise of the **privileges of the pilot certificate**."* It may be hard to demonstrate power on stalls or other powered aircraft maneuvers in a glider... Not saying I doubt you, but there must be some precedent there...

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  [61.56(c)(1)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_156) calls for "an aircraft for which that pilot is rated."  The reg does not require a review for each category/class.

And as further confirmation, AOPA's *[Pilot's Guide to the Flight Review](https://download.aopa.org/epilot/2007/sa03.pdf)* specifically states:

> The satisfactory completion of a flight review allows you to exercise
>   the privilege of pilot in command in all categories and classes of
>   aircraft on your pilot certificate.

Comment: Considering that I have never heard anyone say something to the effect of, "well, I just did by BFR for powered, but I still need to take care of glider" I would think that this is highly likely to be accurate.

Comment: Interesting; I would feel uncomfortable in relying on this BFR in a glider to get back into a powered airplane or helicopter after a year plus of not flying then, if you held certificates and ratings in these aircraft as well, despite the fact that 61.56 allows for it.

Comment: Keep in mind that many "rides" count.  So for example, if you take a commercial glider flight test, that counts towards your flight review applicable to rotorcraft.  This is different, in that you might not already be rated for glider.