# Is a certificated pilot considered to be a student pilot when training in a new category or class?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, student-pilot

Inspired by [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/42587/62), is a pilot certificated in one category or class considered to be a student pilot when training in a new category or class?

To take a specific example, if a pilot holds a Private Pilot - Glider certificate and then decides to add ASEL, is he considered a Student Pilot while he's training for his ASEL? By "considered" I mean, do regulations that refer to "student pilot" apply to the pilot?

Or, to put it as simply as possible: what is the FAA's regulatory definition of "student pilot"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  The regulations that apply to a student pilot do not apply to the private pilot working on a new category or class rating.

> **§61.81   Applicability.**
>
> This subpart prescribes the requirements for the issuance of student pilot certificates, the conditions under which those certificates are necessary, and the general operating rules and limitations for the **holders of those certificates.**

---

The required endorsements for a private pilot working on a new category or class rating are also different.  Student pilots are required to have endorsements for pre-solo flight training, a solo endorsement each 90 days and an endorsement for each cross country.  The student pilot must also abide by all the limitations placed on those endorsements by the recommending instructor.

A private / commercial / ATP pilot working on a new category or class rating is required to have one endorsement.  Again, any limitations placed on the endorsement by the recommending instructor must be followed.

> A.72 To act as pilot in command of an aircraft in solo operations when the pilot does not
> hold an appropriate category/class rating: § 61.31(d)(2).
>
> > I certify that [First name, MI, Last name] has received the training as required by
> > § 61.31(d)(2) to serve as a pilot in command in a [specific category and class] of aircraft.
> > I have determined that [he or she] is prepared to solo that [make and model] aircraft.
> > Limitations: [optional].

Required endorsements for FAA certificated pilots are found in [AC 61-65](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_61-65H.pdf). Version H, issued August 27, 2018, is the latest as of May 2023.